# In Launchpad, can a project own a code branch?

Tags: launchpad

I'm creating my first ever project in Launchpad and have read the [docs about project series](https://help.launchpad.net/Projects/SeriesMilestonesReleases) but I am still a bit confused.

Originally I thought that a project would 'own' branches of code. But, when viewing the 'Configure project branch' page, it appears that this is not possible. The closest thing you get is 'associating' a series to a branch of code that is owned by a team or a person.

So, am I correct in thinking that a 'project' cannot directly 'own a code branch'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, a branch has to be owned by a team or a person.

Often a project has a team associated with it ("foo-dev") which then owns the branch.